# DolphinDB: how to achieve aggregate operations in the reactive state engine?

Tags: streaming, dolphindb

As shown in the following figure, I want to group a stream table by “index“ and perform aggregate calculations using a sliding window of length 2. However, it seems that aggregate operations are not supported in the reactive state engine. How to achieve this in DolphinDB?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two engines and establish a cascade between them: the first is a time-series engine (see DolphinDB user manual - createTimeSeriesEngine), which specifies *keyColumn* as "index" and *metric* as “sum(val)”; the second is a reactive state engine, which specifies *metric* as “msum(val, 2)” and sums the current value with the previous one.